# Sqlite in service

Tags: android, sql, oop

Can anybody tell me what is the best way to access database in a service in a background i have tried

```
SQLiteDatabase db = opOrCreate method
```

but this only works in the UI but in the background it only gives null pointer and i have also tried the.

```
SQliteOpenHelper class
```

this also does not work in services only in the UI.
So my question is that is there a different method of accessing it in the services.

Comment: Using AsyncTask is the best option for back ground process..

Answer (score 0):

Could you please elaborate what exactly you want to do with the database? You could use AsyncTask, it would be best to do anything in background.

Comment: want to retrive data from database in service